# jQuery mouseleave fires an event if input has preselected values

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a sliding loginbox. if i click on a button the login will slide down `$('#loginBox').slideDown()`

the loginbox is wrapping by a div

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative">
 <button>Login</button>
 <div id="loginBox" style="position: absolute"><input name="username" type="text"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseleave', function(){
 $('#loginBox').slideUp();
});
```

if the input username has preselected values and i want to select one, the mosueleave event is fired. and the loginbox will slide up

how can i prevent this?

here is an example code http://jsfiddle.net/XBPmb/3/

Comment: Can you reproduce as a jsfiddle?  Otherwise it's hard to be sure the problem is the code you've provided.

Comment: @MikeEdwards: i updated the post with an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if input has focus on username field:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseleave', function(){
     if( $( this ).find( 'input[name=username]' ).is( ':focus' ) ) {
         return false;
     }
     $('#loginBox').slideUp();
});
```

I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/XBPmb/4/) your jsFiddle to show how it works.

Comment: +1 works fine..is it necessary to loop through all input fields or is it enough to find only one with `$('#wrapper').find('input').is( ':focus' )`

Comment: @JuKe better is to loop. Without it will be ok only for 1 input